# Error 500 when changing .htaccess file on production server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I was previously running a `.htaccess` file on my local development version of my Wordpress site without any issues, but making the equivalent changes to the `.htaccess` file on my production site results in the entire site returning Error 500s.

The site is structured on the server like so:

```
- www.mydomain.com
-- logs
-- public_html
--- (Wordpress root folder)
--- .htaccess
--- index.php 
-- webstats
```

Here is the modified `.htaccess` file that I'm trying to get running on the site:

```
#START WORDPRESS

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public_html/

RewriteRule ^about/?$ /public_html/about/history/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^library/?$ /public_html/the-library/gallery/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

#END WORDPRESS

php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

My understanding of the .htaccess syntax is very lacking, so I can't be sure what I'm getting wrong in the syntax of the file to cause this issue.

Comment: Can you check Apache error.log in production for reason of 500 error?

Comment: have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523135/htaccess-produces-500-internal-server-error ?

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33998266/2776343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great shout to [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) on checking the error.log, I did exactly that and found two discrete errors there.

The first one is the one referenced by [Andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2776343/andrea-manzi):

> Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module
>   not included in the server configuration

I managed to solve this by wrapping the `php_value` block with `<IfModule mod_php.c>` and `</IfModule>`. Note the lack of a version number after `mod_php` - using `mod_php_7` as recommended in many places didn't work for me.

The second error was the following:

> RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL

Because my .htaccess file was located in my document root (which is `public_html` in the case of Siteground hosting), this only needed to be a `/`, and this is also all that was needed in the RewriteRules.

My finished `.htaccess`, with no errors and all redirects working as they should, now looks like this:

```perl
<IfModule mod_php.c>

php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

</IfModule>

#START WORDPRESS

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about/?$ /about/history/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^the-library/?$ /the-library/gallery/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

#END WORDPRESS
```